# Efficient read and write from big text file in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have big text file that contains source-target nodes and threshold.I store all the distinct nodes in HashSet,then filter the edges based on user threshold and store the filtered nodes in separated Hash Set.So i want to find a way to do the processing as fast as possible.

```
public class Simulator {

static HashSet<Integer> Alledgecount = new HashSet<>();
static HashSet<Integer> FilteredEdges = new HashSet<>();

static void process(BufferedReader reader,double userThres) throws IOException {
     String line = null;
     int l = 0;

     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("C:/users/mario/desktop/edgeList.txt"));

     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null & l < 50_000_000) {

            String[] intArr = line.split("\\s+");

            checkDuplicate(Integer.parseInt(intArr[1]), Integer.parseInt(intArr[2]), Alledgecount);

            double threshold = Double.parseDouble(intArr[3]);

            if(threshold > userThres) {  
                writeToFile(intArr[1],intArr[2],writer);

                checkDuplicate(Integer.parseInt(intArr[1]), Integer.parseInt(intArr[2]), FilteredEdges);
             }
        l++;   

     }

     writer.close();

}

static void writeToFile(String param1,String param2,Writer writer) throws IOException {

       writer.write(param1+","+param2);

   writer.write("\r\n");

}
```

The graph class does BFS and writes the nodes in separated file.I have done the processing excluding some functionalities and the timings are below.

Timings with 50 million lines read in process()

```
without calling BFS(),checkDuplicates,writeAllEdgesToFile() -> 54s
without calling BFS(),writeAllEdgesToFile() -> 50s
without calling writeAllEdgesToFile() -> 1min
```

Timings with 300 million lines read in process()

```
without calling writeAllEdges() 5 min
```

Comment: You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. That should be sufficient. There is no reason to believe that attempting to multi-thread it will make it any faster. The disk isn't multi-threaded.

Comment: If you want help optimizing your code, my advice would be to not jump to multi-threading, which is most probably not the right answer here (atleast not the way you're doing it, since all threads read the same file and do the same work, on the same data). Instead, post your mono-thread solution, without omitting key parts such as you checkDuplicate methods, and with an explanation of what the file contains, and what the process is supposed to do.

Comment: ok i have added comments.

Comment: i have used single core but it's very slow it took 6 hours to write 2 million lines in file and input file has 610 million lines

Comment: So you never use Alledgecount and FilteredEdges in your code?

Comment: I will use it at the end to compare BFS edges number with all the edges

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted could be so slow. I took it, made it compile, ran it on a file containing 50 million lines, 1.2GB large, and accepting all the lines (thus writing another file of 50 million lines), and it took 40 seconds. So, extrapolating to 30 GB should just take around 17 minutes. So, either your disk is really, really, really slow, or the code you're executing does much more for each line than what it does in the code you posted (which doesn't compile)

Comment: It may be very slow but have you really narrowed that down to the I/O? By eliminating your processing and measuring?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: I have ssd.I will post all the code to be clear what i am running.My system has i7 6700k, 16gb ram and ssd 500gb

Comment: You have *finally* posted your checkDuplicate method. I asked you to do that yesterday. You're calling contains() twice, at each line. contains is O(n) on an ArrayList. Use a HashSet. HashSet.contains() is O(1). Also, measure the time each step takes. You were also being asked to just measure the IO (i.e. without calling checkDuplicates, and without calling Bfs(), but you didn't do that. You need to know what takes time. Maybe Bfs() is the main time consumer. You should measure to know what to optimize.

Comment: ok thank you.I have noticed that when limit the lines in while statement (process method) is faster than reading from the whole file.

Comment: ok i will use hashset (needs key, value) but i want to store only unique nodes.Maybe using array will be ok for millions of values?

Comment: The more you have distinct values, the more it's important NOT to use an ArrayList, since looking for a value in an ArrayList is O(N): it needs to loop through all elements of the list until it finds the value. A HashSet is O(1): its contains method returns in constant time, whatever the number of elements it contains. Not sure how I can explain that in a better way. You seem to completely misunderstand what I say. I say: "don't use an ArrayList, use a HashSet". And you understand "Maybe using array will be ok for millions of values".

Comment: ok i will check the performance using hashset

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help.It's very fast without using multi-threading.It was the array list contains time complexity that was causing the performance drop.

Comment: How can I improve my question to remove downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a file doesn't depend only on CPU cores.
IO operations on a file will be limited by physical constraints of classic disks that contrary to CPU core cannot parallel operations.

What you could do is having a thread for IO operations and other(s) for data processing but it makes sense only if data processing is long enough to make relevant to create a `Thread` for this task as `Thread`s have a cost in terms of CPU scheduling.

Comment: i have run it for 10 hours to read the file , filter the data and then write them to another file BUT it doesn't finish.I have opened the textfile and i have noticed that only 7 millions lines has been written to the file.I don't know what it's going wrong

Comment: Good explanations sir. Too bad the OP doesn't understand how to ask proper questions ... and puts up a new one, instead of working with folks to get things to work.

Comment: In order the things to work i must get an answer on what i am doing wrong or a sample of code to understand better how to do it.

Comment: Hello @GhostCat , thank you for your good words :) Indeed, creating a new one "identical" question with probably not solve the problem if the first one didn't success

Answer (score 2):

Getting a multi-threaded Java program to run correctly can be very tricky. It needs some deep understanding of things like synchronization issues etc. Without the knowledge/experience necessary, you'll have a hard time searching for bugs that occur sometimes but aren't reliably reproducible.

So, before trying multi-threading, find out if there are easier ways to achieve acceptable performance:

**Find the part of your program that takes the time!**

First question: is it I/O or CPU? Have a look at Task Manager. Does your single-threaded program occupy one core (e.g. CPU close to 25% on a 4-core machine)? If it's far below that, then I/O must be the limiting factor, and changing your program probably won't help much - buy a faster HD. (In some situations, the software style of doing I/O might influence the hardware performance, but that's rare.)

If it's CPU, **use a profiler**, e.g. the JVisualVM contained in the JDK, to find the method that takes most of the runtime and think about alternatives. One candidate might be the `line.split("\\s+")`, using a regular expression. They are slow, especially if the expression isn't compiled to a Pattern beforehand - but that's nothing more than a guess, and the profiler will most probably tell you some very different place.

Comment: Upvote for getting to the core of this: profiling and root cause determination.